# Apache Axis NumberFormatException : Invalid positive Integer

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

When I am trying to consume a web service by sending a **SOAP** message as input using **Apache Axis** I am getting the following error.

Code Snippet :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");


            byte[] fileBytes = null;

            fileBytes=getZipBytes(s); //get the zipped bytes

            SimpleDateFormat formatter =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            Date d=formatter.parse(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));

            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();   
            String uid=trimUUID(uuid.toString());

            String ETIN="11111";
            String EFIN="111111";

            String msgID= ETIN+getJulian7FromDate(d)+uid;

            String timeStamp=simpledateformat.format(calendar.getTime());

            WebServiceLocator fsetlocator=new WebServiceLocator();
            SendSubmissions servicesoap=fsetlocator.getSendSubmissions(s4);


            SOAPHeaderElement soapheaderelement_1 = new SOAPHeaderElement("http://xyz.org", "userHeader"); //Sample URL

            SOAPElement node1 = soapheaderelement_1.addChildElement("Username");   
            node1.addTextNode("admin");   

            SOAPElement node2 = soapheaderelement_1.addChildElement("Password");   
            node2.addTextNode("pwd");

            SOAPHeaderElement soapheaderelement_2 = new SOAPHeaderElement("http://www.abc.com/GatewayService", "msgHeader"); //Sample URL

            SOAPElement node3 = soapheaderelement_2.addChildElement("message");   
            node3.addTextNode(msgID);   

            SOAPElement node4 = soapheaderelement_2.addChildElement("job");   
            node4.addTextNode("Submit");

            SOAPElement node5 = soapheaderelement_2.addChildElement("Timestamp");   
            node5.addTextNode(timeStamp);   


            SOAPElement node8 = soapheaderelement_2.addChildElement("Process");   
            node8.addTextNode("T");      


           ((Stub) servicesoap).setHeader(soapheaderelement_1);
           ((Stub) servicesoap).setHeader(soapheaderelement_2);


            SubmissionDataListType submissiondatalisttype=new SubmissionDataListType();

            String submissionsCount = getCount(s); // returns a count value

            System.out.println("Count : "+submissionsCount);

            submissiondatalisttype.setCount(new PositiveInteger(submissionsCount));

            int cnt=Integer.parseInt(submissionsCount);

            SubmissionDataListTypeSubmissionData submissiondata[] = new SubmissionDataListTypeSubmissionData[cnt];

            for (int i=0 ; i<cnt ; i++){
            submissiondata[i]=new SubmissionDataListTypeSubmissionData();
            UUID uuid1 = UUID.randomUUID();  
            submissiondata[i].setSubmissionId ( EFIN + getJulian7FromDate(d) + trimUUID(uuid1.toString()));
            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            submissiondata[i].setElectronicPostmark(calendar1);
            submissiondata[i].setCategory(CategoryType.StateWH);
            }

            submissiondatalisttype.setSubmissionData(submissiondata);           

            SubmissionDataListType subdatalist=new SubmissionDataListType(new PositiveInteger(submissionsCount),submissiondata);

            SubmissionRecieptListType submissionreceiptlisttype =servicesoap.sendSubmissions(submissiondatalisttype, fileBytes);


            SubmissionRecieptListTypeSubmissionReceipt receipt[] = submissionreceiptlisttype.getSubmissionReceipt();
            FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream("Transmit.txt");
            PrintStream printstream = new PrintStream(fileoutputstream);

            for(int i=0; i<cnt;i++){
            printstream.println(receipt[i].getSubmissionId());
            }
            printstream.close(); 

        } catch(Exception exception)
        {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            throw exception;
        }
```

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: **Invalid positiveInteger:  0**  at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onEndElement(SimpleDeserializer.java:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.endElement(DeserializerImpl.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
>     at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)   at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)    at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
>
> Exception in thread "main" AxisFault  faultCode:
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException 
>   faultSubcode:   faultString: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid
>   positiveInteger:  0  faultActor:   enter code herefaultNode:
>   faultDetail: 
>     {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}**stackTrace:java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   Invalid positiveInteger:  0**     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onEndElement(SimpleDeserializer.java:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.endElement(DeserializerImpl.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
>     at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)   at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)    at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)

I am creating a a Custom SOAP Header and the SOAP Body contains MTOM attachement (zipped XML content in bytes) and an Id(Positive integer value) . I tried to check whether the Id is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Zero is not a positive integer, it is *unsigned*.  Positive integers start with one and go up from there.

Comment: ya tat is fine. I have no idea from where this 0 is originating and how to fix tat in the code. The submissionsCount is always more than 0. So I need to find the place from where this issue is originating and what would be the ideal work around for this.